# how to convert monthly data to quarterly in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have monthly data.  I want to convert it to "periods" of 3 months where q1 starts in January.  So in the example below, the first 3 month aggregation would translate into start of q2 (desired format: 1996q2). And the data value that results from mushing together 3 monthly values is a mean (average) of 3 columns.   Conceptually, not complicated.  Does anyone know how to do it in one swoop? Potentially, I could do a lot of hard work through looping and just hardcode the hell out of it, but I am new to pandas and looking for something more clever than brute force.

```
1996-04   1996-05 1996-06  1996-07 .....
25          19       37      40
```

So I am looking for:

```
1996q2  1996q3   1996q4  1997q1  1997q2 .....
 avg      avg      avg     ...     ...
```

Answer (score 51, accepted):

you can use [pd.PeriodIndex(..., freq='Q')](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#periodindex-and-period-range) in conjunction with  [groupby(..., axis=1)](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html):

```
In [63]: df
Out[63]:
   1996-04  1996-05  2000-07  2000-08  2010-10  2010-11  2010-12
0        1        2        3        4        1        1        1
1       25       19       37       40        1        2        3
2       10       20       30       40        4        4        5

In [64]: df.groupby(pd.PeriodIndex(df.columns, freq='Q'), axis=1).mean()
Out[64]:
   1996Q2  2000Q3    2010Q4
0     1.5     3.5  1.000000
1    22.0    38.5  2.000000
2    15.0    35.0  4.333333
```

---

**UPDATE**: to get columns in a resulting DF as strings intead of `period` dtype:

```
In [66]: res = (df.groupby(pd.PeriodIndex(df.columns, freq='Q'), axis=1)
                  .mean()
                  .rename(columns=lambda c: str(c).lower()))

In [67]: res
Out[67]:
   1996q2  2000q3    2010q4
0     1.5     3.5  1.000000
1    22.0    38.5  2.000000
2    15.0    35.0  4.333333

In [68]: res.columns.dtype
Out[68]: dtype('O')
```

Comment: I've neglected `pd.PeriodIndex`.  I shan't any more.

Comment: @piRSquared, yes, it's pretty convenient

Comment: Unfortunately `pd.PeriodIndex` cause the column names to become in format `pandas.tseries.period.PeriodIndex`. How can I avoid this because I need "2000Q3" as a string?

Comment: I decided to comment because the expected answer of the OP was a dataframe with column like `1996q2 ` and not `1996Q2  `. Therefore, I am trying to obtain the expected answer of the OP

Comment: @MaxU I remember doing a problem on Coursera dealing with just this issue and I struggled.  I wish I had seen this method back then. +1

Comment: @ScottBoston, thank you!  What a coincidence! I'm answering Coursera's quiz at this particular moment... :-)

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to @MaxU's answer above, to convert the resulting `PeriodIndex` columns back to `str` and add spaces between year and quarter number (i.e. `1999 Q1`, not `1999Q1` ), you can do this:

```
res = res.columns.to_series().astype(str)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want your quarters start from April month instead of January, then you have to pass slightly different value to the argument 'feq', which is freq='Q-MAR' and it will calculate q1 as (April to June), q2 as (July to Sept), q3 as (Oct to Dec) and q4 (Jan to Mar)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RBbBv.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please share [code, data and error tracebacks as text, not images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557). Edit your answer accordingly.