# pandas Goup and Rename DataFrame Columns names

Tags: python, pandas

Working with housing value data from Zillow, my dataframe has a series of column names in the form yyyy-mm, example

```
2001-01|2000-02|2000-03|2000-04|...|2016-08
```

Each of these columns contains the average home value for that period for a number of city, state combinations

```
RegionName      State 2000-01  2000-02  2000-03
Philadelphia    PA    53100    53200    53400
```

I need to group the columns but their respective quarter, provide a mean value and return this to a new dataframe. So for the example provided I would have something like the following

```
RegionName     State 2000q1     2000q2 2000q3 2000q4
Philadelphia   PA    53233.33   ...    ...    ...
```

I have no idea how to begin to tackle this. I am able to pull off the column names, get the last two characters, and map those to a dictionary containing the quarter number, but that is it. Not sure how to reassemble the data

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40497199/how-to-convert-monthly-data-to-quarterly-in-pandas/40497246#40497246) answer.

Comment: @NickilMaveli I like the answer in the link you provided. However, I receive and error on the group by "Grouper and axis must be the same length". The data in the file covers January 2000 through August 2016.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is similar to [MaxU's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40497246/190597), but shows a way to groupby **both** the date columns *and* the non-date columns (`RegionName`, `State`).

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'2000-01': [53100], '2000-02': [53200], '2000-03': [53400], 'RegionName': ['Philadelphia'], 'State': ['PA']})

melted = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['RegionName', 'State'], var_name='date')
melted['date'] = pd.PeriodIndex(melted['date'], freq='Q')
result = melted.groupby(['RegionName', 'State', 'date']).mean()
result = result['value'].unstack('date')
```

yields

```
date                2000Q1
RegionName   State        
Philadelphia PA      53233
```

---

First, use `pd.melt` to coalesce all the date columns into a single column:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'2000-01': [53100], '2000-02': [53200], '2000-03': [53400], 'RegionName': ['Philadelphia'], 'State': ['PA']})

melted = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['RegionName', 'State'], var_name='date')
#      RegionName State     date  value
# 0  Philadelphia    PA  2000-01  53100
# 1  Philadelphia    PA  2000-02  53200
# 2  Philadelphia    PA  2000-03  53400
```

Next, use `pd.PeriodIndex` to convert the date (strings?) to `pd.Period`s. Notice that `pd.PeriodIndex` can convert different date strings to the same Period:

```
melted['date'] = pd.PeriodIndex(melted['date'], freq='Q')
#      RegionName State   date  value
# 0  Philadelphia    PA 2000Q1  53100
# 1  Philadelphia    PA 2000Q1  53200
# 2  Philadelphia    PA 2000Q1  53400
```

Finally, use `groupby/mean` to group together rows with the same `RegionName`, `State` and `date` and compute the mean for each group:

```
result = melted.groupby(['RegionName', 'State', 'date']).mean()
#                            value
# RegionName   State date         
# Philadelphia PA    2000Q1  53233
```

If you stop here, your DataFrame will be tidy [(PDF)](http://vita.had.co.nz/papers/tidy-data.pdf) -- each row represents one "observation". This is often the best form for further computation. (It isn't by accident that first step in this solution was to convert the original DataFrame to tidy format -- notice that `melted` also has the property that each row represents one observation.)

However, if you'd like, you could move the `date` index level into separate columns:

```
result = result['value'].unstack('date')
```