# Convert pandas._period.Period type Column names to Lowercase

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset 'City' with Column names

```
2000-01,2000-02,2000-03,2000-04,2000-05,......,2010-08,2010-09,2010-10,2010-11,2010-12.
```

I used the following code and got the column names as

```
2000Q1 , 2000Q2, 2000Q3, ......, 2010Q4
```

in pandas._period.Period datatype.

```
def Problem():
    hd = pd.read_csv('City.csv')
    hd = hd.groupby(pd.PeriodIndex(hd.columns, freq='Q'), axis =1).mean()
    return hd
Problem()
```

I want the columns to be as

```
2000q1, 2000q2, 2000q3, ....... ,2010q4
```

I want lowercase 'q' in my output column names.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `strftime` what works with `PeriodIndex`:

```
hd.columns = hd.columns.strftime('%Yq%q')
```

Sample:

```
hd = pd.DataFrame({'2000-01':[1,3], '2000-05':[5,6]})
hd = hd.groupby(pd.PeriodIndex(hd.columns, freq='Q'), axis =1).mean()
print (hd)
   2000Q1  2000Q2
0       1       5
1       3       6

hd.columns = hd.columns.strftime('%Yq%q')
print (hd)
   2000q1  2000q2
0       1       5
1       3       6
```

Comment: And I dont want column names to be indexed.

Comment: Do you think `0, 1` in sample? Or column names `2000q1` and `2000q2` ? Can you explain more?

Comment: Hey Jezrael, Dont mind the above comment. I got the anwer with strftime. Thanks  man.

Comment: Accepted! Thanks again