# How to change pandas Period Index to lower case?

Tags: pandas, indexing

I have a `dataframe` where I used 
`df.groupby(pd.PeriodIndex(df.columns, freq='Q'), axis=1).mean()` to combine all column names from month into quarter by taking the mean.

However, the result dataframe has columns like below and I could not change all upper case Q into lower case 'q'.

```
PeriodIndex(['2000Q1', '2000Q2', '2000Q3', '2000Q4', '2001Q1', '2001Q2',
             '2001Q3', '2001Q4', '2002Q1', '2002Q2', '2002Q3', '2002Q4',
             '2003Q1', '2003Q2', '2003Q3', '2003Q4', '2004Q1', '2004Q2',
             '2004Q3', '2004Q4', '2005Q1', '2005Q2', '2005Q3', '2005Q4',
             '2006Q1', '2006Q2', '2006Q3', '2006Q4', '2007Q1', '2007Q2',
             '2007Q3', '2007Q4', '2008Q1', '2008Q2', '2008Q3', '2008Q4',
             '2009Q1', '2009Q2', '2009Q3', '2009Q4', '2010Q1', '2010Q2',
             '2010Q3', '2010Q4', '2011Q1', '2011Q2', '2011Q3', '2011Q4',
             '2012Q1', '2012Q2', '2012Q3', '2012Q4', '2013Q1', '2013Q2',
             '2013Q3', '2013Q4', '2014Q1', '2014Q2', '2014Q3', '2014Q4',
             '2015Q1', '2015Q2', '2015Q3', '2015Q4', '2016Q1', '2016Q2',
             '2016Q3'],
            dtype='period[Q-DEC]', freq='Q-DEC')
```

I have tried using `df.columns=[x.lower() for x in df.columns]` and it gives an

> error:'Period' object has no attribute 'lower'

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a duplicate of the issue posted here: [Convert pandas._period.Period type Column names to Lowercase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42330848/convert-pandas-period-period-type-column-names-to-lowercase)

Basically, you'll want to reformat the Period output to have a lowercase q like so:

```
df.columns = df.columns.strftime('%Yq%q')
```

Alternatively, if you want to modify your PeriodIndex object directly, you can do something like:

```
# get the PeriodIndex object you pasted in your question
periods = df.groupby(pd.PeriodIndex(df.columns, freq='Q'), axis=1).mean()
# format the entries accordingly
periods = [p.strftime('%Yq%q') for p in periods]
```

The `%Y` denotes the year format, the first `q` is the lowercase "q" you want, and the `%q` is the quartile.

[Here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Period.strftime.html) is the documentation for a Period's `strftime()` method, which returns the formatted time string. At the bottom they have some nice examples!

Looking at the methods listed in the Pandas [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.Period.html), `lower()` isn't an available method for the Period object, which is why you're getting this error (a PeriodIndex is just an array of Periods, which denote a chunk of time).

Comment: If _you know that it is a duplicate_, please don't answer it. Please indicate as such in the comments with a link to the original, and someone (ex, me) with a badge can mark it as such.

Comment: oh whoops ok good to know!