# Add the remaining quarterly columns that do not have any values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series, pandas-groupby

I have monthly time series data as follows:

```
  Item  2020 Jan  2020 Feb  2020 Mar  2020 Jul  2020 Aug  2020 Sep
0    A         0         1         2         3         4         5
1    B         5         4         3         2         1         0
```

I needed to convert this monthly data into quarterly data as a sum of three months, so I adapted the code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40497246/9212050) to do just that:

```
df = df.groupby(pd.PeriodIndex(df.columns, freq='Q'), axis=1).sum()
```

The resulting `df` is as follows:

```
  Item  2020 Q1  2020 Q3
0    A        3       12
1    B       12        3
```

However, I wanted to have all quarters listed in between, not just the ones that have a value larger than 0. So my desired output is as follows:

```
  Item  2020 Q1  2020 Q2  2020 Q3
0    A        3        0       12
1    B       12        0        3
```

So in this output, there is an additional column `Q2` because it is between the first and the last quarter periods, even though it has no positive values. Does anybody know how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandawheres.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) with [`period_range`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.period_range.html):

```
df = df.set_index('Item')
df.columns = pd.to_datetime(df.columns)

df = df.groupby(pd.PeriodIndex(df.columns, freq='Q'), axis=1).sum()
df = df.reindex(pd.period_range(df.columns.min(), df.columns.max(), freq='Q'), axis=1, fill_value=0)
print (df)
      2020Q1  2020Q2  2020Q3
Item                        
A          3       0      12
B         12       0       3
```